# Android: How do I call an activity when service is destroyed (onDestroy)?

Tags: java, android, service, android-activity, android-ndk

Does anyone know how to call an activity when a service is destroyed? I have tried with the code below, but it doesn't work and geves me a `force close`.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Intent goToAbout = new Intent(this, AboutForm.class);
    startActivity(goToAbout);
}
```

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void onDestroy(){
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this,
            MyACtivity.class);
    myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    getApplication().startActivity(myIntent);
}
```